# Bottom button moves up when keyboard opens

Tags: android

There is a scrollview & button(at the bottom) inside linear layout. Toolbar is fixed for the screen. When keyboard opens, button moves up. I want the button not to move up.

Comment: can you add your screen screenshot

Comment: can you share your xml file

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Fragment write the below code in **onCreateView**:

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code to change the your `manifest.xml` ,,For which xml layout contains activity.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged|adjustResize"
```

OR

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
```

Change in MANIFEST FILE

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.adjustscroll.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged|adjustResize"
         >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Hope this will help you. Let me know if solved.

Comment: this is right done by using android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize" ,, thanks

Comment: adjustPan is working but it will restrict scroll!! @Zain

Comment: @ArnoldBrown I guess I have trouble with that.. Can you please check in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59492019/making-the-whole-layout-smaller-when-the-keyboard-appears/59492293#59492293)

Answer (score 0):

In your XML file, you can use ScrollView:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!--your layout-->

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your activity has the following attribute in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Also in the layout xml file has `LinearLayout` as the parent for `Button` and `EditText`.

Answer (score 0):

Here issue with manifest property for that activity.

Have you added any property at manifest like below ?

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Or

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```