# Making the whole layout smaller when the keyboard appears

Tags: java, android

I made a new fragment for creating a new playlist, but when you focus the EditText the buttons below aren't visible. Setting "`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize"`" or only "`adjustResize`" didn't fix the problem.

That's the code of my layout for the fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/default_fullscreen_dialog"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="24dp">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/object_create_playlist_dialog_title"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_above="@id/dialog_cp_playlistname"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/dialog_cp_playlistname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:autofillHints=""
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:lines="1"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@color/white_50"
            android:textSize="35sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/white_50"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:stretchColumns="1,0"
            android:layout_below="@id/dialog_cp_playlistname"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true">

            <TableRow >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/dialog_cp_cancel"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/transparent"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
                    android:gravity="end|center_vertical"
                    android:paddingStart="0dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="25dp"
                    android:text="@string/object_cancel"
                    android:textColor="@color/white_70"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/dialog_cp_next"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/transparent"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
                    android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
                    android:paddingStart="25dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="0dp"
                    android:text="@string/object_next"
                    android:textColor="@color/accent_color"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

That's the style that I use for the fragment:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent_color</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/WindowAnimationStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">#ffffff</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Dialog.CreatePlaylist">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent_color</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:textSelectHandleLeft">@drawable/null_shape</item>
    <item name="android:textSelectHandleRight">@drawable/null_shape</item>
    <item name="android:textSelectHandle">@drawable/null_shape</item>
</style>
```

MyApp:

[image: My App]
[image: My App with Keyboard]

I would like to (Spotify):

[image: I would like to (Spotify)]
[image: I would like to with Keyboard(Spotify)]

I would be glad about an answer.

Comment: Is your activity using full screen mode in its theme? because this seems to be a known issue for a while now https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417123/android-how-to-adjust-layout-in-full-screen-mode-when-softkeyboard-is-visible

Comment: I've seen that post before , but it didn't work. Thank's for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now the hole answer.
**DON'T** use `windowTranslucentStatus` in your style rather use `windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds` and set `statusBarColor`.
e.g.:

```
 <style name="AppTheme.Dialog.CreatePlaylist">
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>     
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">[some color]</item>
 </style>
```

By the way you needn't change your layout.

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

Add below attribute for your activity that holds this fragment in the manifest file

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged|adjustResize"
```

Sample

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged|adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Please let me know if it doesn't work to think differently

> EDIT

**Steps:**

1. Keep using `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged|adjustResize"` as
   mentioned before
2. Wrap your fragment layout in `ScrollView` or `NestedScrollView`

**How it looks like**

[image]

**Here is a demo that worked with me**

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

**MainActivity Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:name="com.example.android.androidxtest.TempFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**MainFragment**

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    }
}
```

**MainFragment Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="24dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/object_create_playlist_dialog_title"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/dialog_cp_playlistname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:lines="1"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textSize="35sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:stretchColumns="1,0">

            <TableRow>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/dialog_cp_cancel"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/object_cancel"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/dialog_cp_next"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/object_next"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Hope this works!

Comment: No I didn't chage something

Answer (score 0):

I think , maybe there is a problem in the manifest file. check whether that your manifest file has the fragment.

Comment: The Manifest-Part of my Activity: `<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.MainActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged|adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>` (based on the answer before)